# why do I keep getting TypeErrors whenever I run the discord bot code?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, dotenv

whenever I type into the terminal node install index.js it either shows up as TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client, or TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS'). I've already installed dotenv and discord.js.

I was trying to make the discord bot always say Obama because a friend of mine wanted me to do that. I was expecting the bot to actually work but instead, it kept giving me errors in the terminal every time I tried to run it.

Here's the code:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!Barack') {
    const messages = ['Obama'];
    const response = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    message.channel.send(response);
  }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

Comment: `Intents.FLAGS` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

`Intents` has now changed to `GatewayIntentBits` in discord.js, you can try the following code.

```
const {Client, GatewayIntentBits} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages]});


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content === '!Barack') {
        const messages = ['Obama'];
        const response = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
        message.channel.send(response);
    }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```